# Should e-Mail adresses be edited away?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, email

I'm still pretty new to Ask Ubuntu. I've seen some people include their e-mail address in their [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354887/i-cant-install-ubuntu-in-my-system).

Is it okay to edit the e-Mail address away as I feel they break the way Ask Ubuntu works?

Comment: Quick answer: YES

Comment: What jokerdino said. This would prevent the email from getting spam and other annoying problems.

Comment: @jokerdino if it is an 'answer' as you say, just post it as an answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the site software won't take "yes" for an answer. ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: YES!

Emails in questions/answers pose at least 2 problems:

- Spam: Spambots are very good at filtering plain text emails off websites.  (This is why most people, when sharing emails, type them `name AT host DOT com` etc)
- The site doesn't work this way. Questions should be asked here *as well as* answered here and the problem should be *discussed* here. That's how the site is supposed to work.

So ultimately, yes, adding your email to your question breaks the way the site was designed to work and exposes you to spam.

Comment: I should point out that spam bots are good at recognizing the "user AT domain DOT com" format as well. In fact, the only way to really beat spam bots is to omit part of the address and imply the missing parts from context.